# Testing for Nuget package version collisions in a devops pipeline BEFORE push

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

So I have a solution of multiple project containing project which build DLLs I want to push to nuget.

People especially me are idiots and get things wrong, even automation can get things wrong.

What I am attempting to achieve is to check there are no version-number collisions/violations before I do a nuget push.

To try ensure that the push stage won't fail half way through, due to said collision.

Answer (score 0):

> What I am attempting to achieve is to check there are no version-number collisions/violations before I do a nuget push.

As a long-term user of azure devops and nuget, we do not need to check again if there are version-number collisions before we push nuget package.

That because nuget push task or push command line has a built-in check command, if there are the same version, they will fail the task and inform nuget version of the conflict. This is a reasonable expected result.

If you want to ensure that the push stage won't fail half way, what is your next step after you get there is version-number collisions, fail your pipeline or stop push the pushing? This has the same result as our direct fail nuget push.

Besides, the failure push phase will not have other negative effects, nuget package will not be push to the feed.

Note: If you access version-number collisions when you push the nuget package, the there is an option `Allow duplicates to be skipped`, which allows the task to report success even if some of your packages are rejected with 409 Conflict errors:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: So the solution has multiple projects each with its own nuget package.

I want to avoid a situation I publish one package which references another, which will fail to publish when push, resulting in my publishing a nuget package which refences a non-existant project.

IMHO Allowing duplicates just hides the problem, as oppose to solving it.